# Custom Search for contacts in android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider, android-contacts

I want to custom search in contacts in android.

For example, i want contacts that **each contact number end with 555** so how can i do that?

Comment: refer to http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html. It shows how to create an adapter and everything. If you implement onCreateLoader you can pass the search parameters that you require.

Comment: @max posted my code below, did you find it useful...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get all contacts and search manually using code.

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver(); 
Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null); 
String phone = null;
if (cur.getCount() > 0) { 
  while (cur.moveToNext()) { 
    String id = cur.getString(cur .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID)); 
    if (Integer .parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) 
    { 
      Cursor pCur = cr.query( ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null); 
      while (pCur.moveToNext()) { 
        phone = pCur .getString(pCur .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)); 
        if(phone.endsWith( "555")
             // store the number and id of the contact
      } 
      pCur.close(); 
    } 
    /*** Store id and phone in another variable(eg ArrayList,etc) so that it does not get lost in another iteration of while loop***/
  }
}
```

Also Android contacts are formatted with spaces,- and (). it may be better to remove them before checking. Using

```
phone.replace("-", "").replace("(", "").replace(")", "").replace(".", "").replace(" ", "");
```

Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26859338/check-incoming-number-is-stored-in-contacts-list-or-not-android/26859482#26859482).

Comment: thanks mohammad ali i see your answer but i'm looking for faster way ,my be i find it.

Comment: Also see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26859338/check-incoming-number-is-stored-in-contacts-list-or-not-android/26859482#26859482  It uses PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI it is faster than above code...

Comment: did you find faster way?