# Unreliable result for checking incoming number in contact

Tags: java, android

I  am using code listed here [Check Incoming number is stored in Contacts list or not android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26859338/check-incoming-number-is-stored-in-contacts-list-or-not-android) for checking whether incoming number exist or not in contacts. This code does not give correct result always.

Is there some correction required in this or some other better way to check?

---

**Code:**

```
String res = null;
try {
    ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
    String a = uri.getLastPathSegment();
    Cursor c = resolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER}, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID + "=?", new String[]{a}, null);

    if (c != null) { // cursor not null means number is found contactsTable
        if (c.getCount() > 0) {
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {   // so now find the contact Name
            res = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            //res = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        }
        c.close();
        }
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
return res;
```

Comment: "This code does not give correct result always." So why not provide some details then? Explain why you need to post a duplicate question as well.

Comment: why you catched the exception and ignore it, this way you will **NEVER** get exact results.

Comment: @Panache  **you don't know how he have earned 5962 points** it takes hardwork of more than a year or two,  don't blame someone as he is wasting his time for you, be polite and check the below answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code its simple & working for me.

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {

private static final int REQUEST_CONTACT_NUMBER = 8512885487;

/** Pops the "select phone number" window */
public void onBrowseForNumbersButtonClicked(View view) {
    Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Phone.CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, REQUEST_CONTACT_NUMBER);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    if(data != null && requestCode == REQUEST_CONTACT_NUMBER) {  
    Uri uriOfPhoneNumberRecord = data.getData();
    String idOfPhoneRecord = uriOfPhoneNumberRecord.getLastPathSegment();
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, new String[]{Phone.NUMBER}, Phone._ID + "=?", new String[]{idOfPhoneRecord}, null);
    if(cursor != null) {
    if(cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String formattedPhoneNumber = cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER) );
        Log.d("TestActivity", String.format("The selected phone number is: %s", formattedPhoneNumber));
    }
    cursor.close();
    }
    }
else {
    Log.w("TestActivity", "WARNING: Corrupted request response");
}
}
else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
    Log.i("TestActivity", "Popup canceled by user."); 
}
else {
    Log.w("TestActivity", "WARNING: Unknown resultCode");
}
}
}
```

Comment: still same issue, number is saved but code is not finding it.

Comment: @Panache debug and check what is the issue, and help yourself.

Comment: @Panache no one can help you if you don't want to help urself.